# Using TrueCrypt for encrypting user profiles on another volume

Tags: windows-7, truecrypt, user-profiles

My computer (Windows 7) is equipped with two hard disks. One is for the system partition, Windows and the applications while the other contains the `Users` folder. Now I'd like to encrypt my volumes with TrueCrypt. No problem for the system partition but how about the second volume?

Windows needs access to the user profiles on the second drive when logging in. But it cannot get access until the volume has been mounted in TrueCrypt.

Is there any way of using TrueCrypt with a `Users` folder on another drive?

Answer (score 0):

I think [System Favorite Volumes](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/system-favorites) should handle this without any issues, as you already are using an encrypted system partition.